# I cant make a class which deletes special signs

Tags: python, oop, typeerror

I cant make a class which deletes special signs

```
class StripChars:
    def __init__(self, chars):
        self.__chars = chars

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(args, str):
            raise TypeError('Argument must be str')

        return args.strip(self.__chars)

s = StripChars('?!.;')
res = s('Hello World!')
print(res)
```

It always raises TypeError

Comment: Try printing the type of args or using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a tuple, not a string. Use `args[0]` instead.

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(args[0], str):
        raise TypeError('Argument must be str')

    return args[0].strip(self.__chars)
```

Or, if you always input 1 parameter at a time, you can do like the code below. There is no need for `*args`.

```
def __call__(self, string):
    if not isinstance(string, str):
        raise TypeError('Argument must be str')

    return string.strip(self.__chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because args in this case is tuple of positional arguments and string that you passed to s instance is first argument of this tuple. You can use

```
if not isinstance(args[0], str):
...
```

or the better choice in my opinion is

```
def __call__(self, some_string):
    if not isinstance(some_string, str):
    ...
```

My bad, I am a bit late and good answer is already given :)